# SQL Statement on Date Fields that will insert and update another column with a specific number

Tags: sql, conditional-statements

I am new to SQL but I do pretty well, but I am stumped on how to do this.  I want to pull service information from our AR Ledger based on a Fiscal Year PostDate, then I want to insert a column and based on the PostDate I want the column to update with the Fiscal Year Month.  Example below

If the Post Date is between 1/1/2022 and 1/31/2022 in the new column I want it to put the #7
If the Post Date is between 2/1/2022 and 2/28/2022 in the new column I want it to put the #8
and so on for all 12 months of the Fiscal Year.

I can write the select query however, I don't know how to add the column and then update it based on the breakout of the dates with the Fiscal Year Month.  Can anyone help.  I'm sure there is a much easier way of doing this.  Also I don't use the "AS" clause to rename all the tables and columns.

```
SELECT 
    dbo.ARLedger.RecordDeleted, 
    dbo.ARLedger.LedgerType, 
    dbo.GlobalCodes.CodeName, 
    Sum(dbo.ARLedger.Amount) AS SumOfAmount, 
    dbo.ARLedger.PostedDate, 
    dbo.ARLedger.CoveragePlanId, 
    dbo.ARLedger.ClientId, 
    Count(dbo.Charges.BillingCode) AS CountOfBillingCode, 

FROM 
    ((dbo.ARLedger INNER JOIN dbo.Charges ON dbo.ARLedger.ChargeId = dbo.Charges.ChargeId) 
    INNER JOIN dbo.Services ON dbo.Charges.ServiceId = dbo.Services.ServiceId) 
    INNER JOIN dbo.GlobalCodes ON dbo.ARLedger.AdjustmentCode = dbo.GlobalCodes.GlobalCodeId

WHERE 
    (((dbo.ARLedger.PostedDate) Between '7/1/2021' And '6/30/2022'))

GROUP BY 
    dbo.ARLedger.RecordDeleted, 
    dbo.ARLedger.LedgerType, 
    dbo.GlobalCodes.CodeName, 
    dbo.ARLedger.PostedDate, 
    dbo.ARLedger.CoveragePlanId, 
    dbo.ARLedger.ClientId, 
    dbo.ARLedger.DateOfService, 
    dbo.Charges.RecordDeleted, 
    dbo.Services.RecordDeleted

HAVING 
    (((dbo.ARLedger.RecordDeleted) Is Null) 
    AND ((dbo.ARLedger.LedgerType)=4203) 
    AND ((dbo.Charges.RecordDeleted) Is Null) 
    AND ((dbo.Services.RecordDeleted) Is Null));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to both your select and group statements. This should continue to work regardless of year.

```
    case when month(dbo.ARLedger.PostedDate) = 1 then '#7'
    when month(dbo.ARLedger.PostedDate) = 2 then '#8'
    when month(dbo.ARLedger.PostedDate) = 3 then '#9'
    when month(dbo.ARLedger.PostedDate) = 4 then '#10'
    when month(dbo.ARLedger.PostedDate) = 5 then '#11'
    when month(dbo.ARLedger.PostedDate) = 6 then '#12'
    when month(dbo.ARLedger.PostedDate) = 7 then '#1'
    when month(dbo.ARLedger.PostedDate) = 8 then '#2'
    when month(dbo.ARLedger.PostedDate) = 9 then '#3'
    when month(dbo.ARLedger.PostedDate) = 10 then '#4'
    when month(dbo.ARLedger.PostedDate) = 11 then '#5'
    when month(dbo.ARLedger.PostedDate) = 12 then '#6'
    end
```

Comment: that worked perfect.  Thank you for your help.  If I responded in the wrong place I apologize, this is my first day here at Stack, still learning.